# Curvature of the graph of a function defined on a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I am not an expert in differential geometry and was wondering: Given a function $h:\mathbb S^{n-1} \longrightarrow \mathbb R $ smooth, the graph of $h$ is an $(n-1)$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$. How can I compute the mean curvature of this submanifold in terms of $h$ with regards to the metric on the sphere?

Here, $\mathbb S^{n-1} := \{z \in \mathbb R^n: |z| = 1\}$ is the unit sphere seen as a smooth Riemannian submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$.

What I am especially interested in is the case $n=3$ and I am looking for an explicit formula.

Can anyone provide an answer/formula, or a reference?

Thank you guys very much for your help.